# Base table or view not found

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'grandmaspizza.DailyOffer'

[Screenshot of Base Table](http://prntscr.com/dsff64)

As you can see, the table is created, but still that error shows up.

On localhost it works all correctly, but when I place it online it wont work no matter what I try to do.

Have read that it could be a database corruption, do you think that could be it?

Comment: Your server has Mysql Case sensitive turned on, your localhost does not

Comment: Thanks guys, it helped me alot :)